# Problem with matplotlib when installing QGIS on mac

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, matplotlib

I have matplotlib installed on a Mac (Mavericks) via `pip`, which means the matplotlib files get installed under /System/Library/...

I tried installing the most recent version of QGIS, and the install fails because it can't find matplotlib. I'm thinking this is because I didn't use `easy_install`, which appears to put packages instead under /Library/...

Is there an easy way to tell QGIS to look for packages under /System/Library - is it merely a matter of setting some environment variable that QGIS looks at ?

thanks !

Update:

- I'm installing QGIS from the .dmg package provided at [kyngchaos.com](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)
- the error message started when I double click the .dmg to install it. I get a popup complaining that matplotlib is not installed even though it is installed and command line python can see it.

I believe (based on other notes at kyngchaos.com) that the difference is because of my use of python.org python and `pip` instead of system python, and the different place that libraries are placed in.

Comment: Please provide more information. How are you installing QGIS (method and from what source)? When you say the install fails, in what way, e.g. error in an installer? BTW, Python packages should _never_ need to be installed in /System/Library/... and `pip` should not be installing files there, i.e. if it is, there is something wrong.

Comment: could you uninstall matplotlib and reinstall using the methods outlined at [kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)? This works well for me on Mavericks. Is there any particular reason you need to do things differently?

Comment: @StephenLead is correct (please add as answer). The KyngChaos install does not support non-system Python installs; so, you will need to install `matplotlib` in system Python's site-packages. The best means is to [use KyngChaos's installer](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python).

Comment: i have same problem. matplotlib is in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib and the qgis installer is not picking it up. rather than uninstalling it, what can i do to make the qgis installer pick it up from this directory?

Comment: i even tried moving matplotlib to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib but the QGIS installer still cannot find it. it is super lame!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you uninstall `matplotlib` and reinstall using the methods outlined at [Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)?

This works well for me on Mavericks. Is there any particular reason you need to do things differently?

As noted by @dakcarto above, it appears that

> The KyngChaos install does not support non-system Python installs; so,
>   you will need to install `matplotlib` in system Python's site-packages.
>   The best means is to use KyngChaos's installer.

Comment: There are various reasons that pip is a cleaner installer than other methods (SO has various threads on this). But I did as you suggest and was able to get QGIS to install. Thanks !

Comment: Installing `matplotlib` via a version of `pip` built against the system Python will also work. You can also use Homebrew and the [homebrew-python tap](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-python), as long as the `matplotlib` formula is not built against Homebrew's Python.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. My `matplotlib` is installed under `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`. In case anyone is interested, I was able to solve this problem by running this command:

```
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override
```

now run the installer and it should work fine and you just saved yourself from installing `matplotlib` twice! 
do `man ln` to understand what the command does.

The problem is not because of your use of python.org python and pip instead of system python, and the different place that libraries are placed in.

It is due to the fact that the installer that is hardcoded to look for matplotlib under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override`. Further the installer does not provide user to specify path of `matplotlib` at time of installation.